# C# Using a random number gen with a key to solve an encrypted message but I cannot get the message to keep within the string

Tags: c#, arrays, encryption

For my problem I am experiencing today comes in the form of a string array. The goal of this assignment is to use Random with a seed value of 243 as a key to access a hidden message from 22 lines. Within these 22 lines are 5 letters that form a word. Here is 22 lines containing 60 characters in each line and the goal is to use the key to pick the 5 letters from each line.

```
String[] line = { "<?JRrP*h^vtVc^ppOZI@PCAa{ (n1>&VSf~59eI7Tn5We^77O/CEvgdq}gU0",
                              "G;t@o=#|^ZWV01`a-h{=Js>!z`_j!&7PB9nCgtfHZ:WtWk4e&#k5i7uV{$E/",
                              "]7zXf&4uA=n8!Sa08IIoKyc~:#d*T8FcOWjB?~QQ =Ch(S37UT>RYobbSz>@",
                              "w*A)v5gHh>p9vvVeUzvfmMT~tr)8s(nC`11Lz:qhjjN6c$Z ^T,W$VQqUB/#",
                              "+NSrOLhed*2;)$z#}=;t7FY?z6?e^?cX+nf;6me6Kt|TBpN ZNr7&9j t4c8",
                              "-N&E2X/:<_k0W$HpH${*f?M0K_Qp##F!)M){nVAu`4bzab_too;m8YPm!tyR",
                              "s=69 j&*yLRpb2IR[RNg~O!ZfUhr{czx]mbB}Hau]T(CtI-%0}1NFeRV<ZRb",
                              "!U-]QY4sN&S2pW+JGaenHc?|)KQJ:,&Cu}s'GIp:59U)J~]n&(/^s6:=htS ",
                              "'iXi 0;qbk#|kn&/-5Q*mbC2|FN_bVp6tk3K_3):bj+#%1 I/+0 ]I6CEFDX",
                              " [/,2k( 7ZNy,7GlV@,kk$PVEpXKTn&8mPX&[~o9)q2S]6rs!3k$:i$]*WeA",
                              "3[KGT5+Z^@FWPt aq{y/|2I@#!}5Kzz$9M&LFieF*8f_l4RGuBie]UD!2+Dh",
                              "7u.qDs=#k5:' S$dKiRmMU>)1lFb)%:;EL/4)#:Juu[_'a1)Q_TGWUe`V%QW",
                              "zZxtz~aOCoZGN(vny]#N[=1IOqbnGN]iQbN;Vtc' od`$-xN^&ex##z]HO )",
                              "<q(t2VukYZf%yyNzWODBw40wgc!Nfpr&]Yj- oNM6-t#^`h(R %o+s0'af-N",
                              "Ut$gg@F?/@Bg!v+j>,aedrzekyzhebJpb wo(-:>:hw1]<v3hEgU%&h]J=zm",
                              "D]uLuP$ ~;b1pBk% usN#f #ytk[6:Di1Lx[hK;,7u4mbVca:b[` bk]]qQ ",
                              "dHicvw De/<SM{7+QR@n0iAR^bUe_;}uy;Fr,PUiV?8*F(37a`++Q.nZ&6%3",
                              "Bcc-1EY1UG} {a on6,UN=P~/rDjKkguKBG<[*xsM#akb+/zA}gn*Nc$hc}>",
                              " ndhw'TX-O4f=* LZc<#cHIL#xk|]BSv+Z!^<s-ZUUlpi!Q~F7IimyZVD7de",
                              ":Vzi{=[b)HEaV`M-[Wb#FlVFxNN0 I9. G?}Z#tKDmu|'gM LLzlT->M TpL",
                              "mKb^.+i/@NRXa7]XuX>1!gbR LOQ(q}%1H]x+.mz:=D}xB*<$eWDj_J%g/0a",
                              "[{&NOLF9YcL^iCvcBcY+A2LB:UoQ|V1{s,?>7krK{pb@8w]pgfa#U$tHNbay" };
```

For the chunk of code that I am working on comes here.

```
String[] decrypted = new String[22];
            var randNum = new Random(243);
            int i, k;



            for (i = 0; i < 22; i++)
            {

                String currentLine = line[i];


                for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                {
                    decrypted[i] = Convert.ToString(currentLine[randNum.Next(0, 60)]);
                    
                }
                
            }

            printIt(decrypted);


            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void printIt(string[] decrypted)
        {
            var build = new StringBuilder();

                for (int h = 0; h < 22; h++)
                {
                build.Append(Convert.ToString(decrypted[h]));
                }

            Console.WriteLine(build);
```

The help I am looking for is to understand how I can store the 5 characters from each line successfully within the decrypted array.

I can gain the correct answer if I insert directly in my nested for loop the `Console.WriteLine(decrypted[i]);`

However, if I try to pull the same line anywhere after the for loop containing random, I only am able to pull the first letter of each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your loop to:

```
    String[] decrypted = new String[110];

    for (i = 0; i < 22; i++)
    {
        String currentLine = line[i];
        for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
        {
            decrypted[k + i * 5] = Convert.ToString(currentLine[randNum.Next(0, 60)]);
        }
    }
```

And Print:

```
static void printIt(string[] decrypted)
{
    var build = new StringBuilder();

    for (int h = 0; h < decrypted.Length; h++)
    {
        build.Append(Convert.ToString(decrypted[h]));
    }

    Console.WriteLine(build);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my own problem after doing a bit more research and deduction of what I could possibly be missing. Here is the solution.

```
for (i = 0; i < 22; i++)
            {

                String currentLine = line[i];


                for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                {
                    decrypted[i] = decrypted[i] + Convert.ToString(currentLine[randNum.Next(0, 60)]);
                    //Adding the previous character to the new character to help build up the string.
                }
```

It was after I realized I wasn't building up the characters properly I chose to add the previous character and it solved my problem.

Comment: This sure works but it creates more strings in the process because of the concatenation. Strings are immutable.